# IntelliSense while in snippet (VSCode)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was wondering how do I get suggestions from Intellisense while I'm editing snippet-generated text (more precisely, in import statements).

Right now when I'm inside a snippet there are no suggestions:
[image: in-snippet]
But if I type the same manually I do get them:
[image: manual]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that this setting fixes the issue:

```json
"editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false
```